# Selenium webdriver python cannot find button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to locate the save button after filling a form but it failed, I tried with xpath and classname, css selector...but neither of them worked. Strange is that if I wrote a different test when only testing the button it worked, but after filling the form it didn't (the form itself and the buttons are under the same form tag).
This is my code:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btn-group.form-buttons > button[name=\"save\"]")))

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn-group.form-buttons > button[name=\"save\"]").click()
```

The xpath of the button: `/html/body/main/section/fieldset[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/button[1]`

Any idea why selenium can't find it? Please give me a solution?

Comment: Share the relevant HTML

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Op9l.png

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code and lets see if t works for you-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn-group.form-buttons > button[name=\"save\"]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

update

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-alert.btn-gradient.btn-save-form:first-child")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

update 2

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit'][name='save'][data-speech='Create']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: not working :( selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: div.btn-group.form-buttons > button[name="save"]

Comment: show me your DOM. I think cssselector is incorrect.

Comment: :(( selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: button.btn.btn-alert.btn-gradient.btn-save-form:first-child

Comment: can u give URL?

Comment: solved it with adding driver.switch_to.default_content() before trying to find the button